# Liquibase: how to revert back my DB to a previous state in that case

Tags: load-testing, liquibase

I am quite a newbie on Liquibase and despite my search I didn't find any relevant information regarding my case:

I am going to do a load testing on my web app.

This load test will write a lot of data in my database, and at the end of the test, I want my database looks like it was before the test.

How can I do that by command line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase doesn't really deal with the data - so if you want to do something like this you would need to do something like use the database's native backup/restore commands, or else use something like `liquibase dropAll`, followed by `liquibase update` to re-populate the schema.

Comment: Thanks for the answers ;)